# Sqlite substract sums (with group by) with JOIN and duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sum

I previously found the solution to my problem but unfortunately I lost files on my harddrive and I can't find the statement I managed to produce.

I have 2 tables T2REQ and T2STOCK, both have 2 columns (typeID and quantity) and my problem reside in the fact that I can have multiple occurences of SAME typeID in BOTH tables.

What I'm trying to do is SUM(QUANTITY) grouped by typeID and substract the values of T2STOCK from T2REQ but since I have multiple occurences of same typeID in both tables, the SUM I get is multiplied by the number of occurences of typeID.

Here's a sample of T2REQ (take typeID 11399 for example):

```
typeID      quantity
----------  ----------
34          102900
35          10500
36          3220
37          840
11399       700
563         140
9848        140
11486       28
11688       700
11399       390
4393        130
9840        390
9842        390
11399       390
11483       19.5
11541       780
```

And this is a sample of T2STOCK table :

```
typeID      quantity
----------  ----------
9842        1921
9848        2400
11399       1700
11475       165
11476       27
11478       28
11481       34
11483       122
11476       2
```

And this is where I'm at for now, I know that the SUM(t2stock.quantity) is affected (multiplied) because of the JOIN 1 = 1 but whatever I tried, I'm not doing it in the right order:

```
        SELECT 
           t2req.typeID, sum(t2req.quantity), sum(t2stock.quantity),
           sum(t2req.quantity) - sum(t2stock.quantity) as diff 
        FROM t2req JOIN t2stock ON t2req.typeID = t2stock.typeID 
        GROUP BY t2req.typeID 
        ORDER BY diff DESC;

typeID      sum(t2req.quantity)  sum(t2stock.quantity)  diff
----------  -------------------  ---------------------  ----------
563         140                  30                     110
11541       780                  780                    0
11486       28                   40                     -12
11483       19.5                 122                    -102.5
9840        390                  1000                   -610
40          260                  940                    -680
9842        390                  1921                   -1531
9848        140                  2400                   -2260
11399       1480                 5100                   -3620
39          650                  7650                   -7000
37          1230                 116336                 -115106
36          28570                967098                 -938528
35          33770                2477820                -2444050
34          102900               2798355                -2695455
```

You can see that SUM(t2req) for typeID 11399 is correct : 1480

And you can see that the SUM(t2stock) for typeID 11399 is not correct : 5100 instead of 1700 (which is 5100 divided by 3, the number of occurences in t2req)

What would be the best way to avoid multiplications because of multiple typeIDs (in both tables) with the JOIN for my sum substract ?

Sorry for the wall of text, just trying to explain as best as I can since english is not my mother tongue.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate before join:

```
SELECT 
   t2req.typeID, 
   t2req.quantity, 
   t2stock.quantity,
   t2req.quantity - t2stock.quantity as diff 
FROM 
    (SELECT TypeID, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM t2req GROUP BY TypeID) t2req JOIN 
    (SELECT TypeID, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM t2stock GROUP BY TypeID) t2stock 
        ON t2req.typeID = t2stock.typeID 
ORDER BY diff DESC;
```

Fiddle sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/06711/5

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single aggregation:

```
    SELECT 
       COALESCE(r.typeID, s.typeID) AS typeID,
       COALESCE(r.quantity, 0) AS req_quantity,
       COALESCE(s.quantity, 0) AS stock_quantity,
       COALESCE(r.quantity, 0) - COALESCE(s.quantity, 0) AS diff
    FROM (
            SELECT rr.typeID, SUM(rr.quantity) AS quantity 
            FROM t2req rr
            GROUP BY rr.typeID
        ) r
    CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT ss.typeID, SUM(ss.quantity) AS quantity 
            FROM t2stock ss 
            GROUP BY ss.typeID
        ) s ON r.typeID = s.typeID
    ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```